# How can I select row data to display it on other inputs using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I already get the results from query to display them on a table it looks like this.
**table that shows all employees**
[image: table that shows all employees]

Then I can do a search query to get the specific employee I´m looking for:
**search for name result**
[image: search for name result]
The question is how can I choose or pick that result to display that information in a form or table or anything I can use to pass those results to other inputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Busqueda de empleados</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" id="myform1">
        ver todos los empleados:
        <input type="text" name="buscar">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar1" id="enviar1" value="enviar">
        <hr>
    </form>

            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
     <thead>
      <tr class= "info" bgcolor='#B9EDFD'>
        <th >INTERNO</th>
        <th>CURP</th>
        <th>NOMBRE</th>
        <th>A_PATERNO</th>
        <th>A_MATERNO</th>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
        foreach ($empleados-> result() as $row) {
          echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td bgcolor='#EAECEE'>".$row->Interno;"</td>";
                echo "<td bgcolor='#EAECEE'>".$row->Curp;"</td>";
                  echo "<td bgcolor='#EAECEE'>".$row->Nombre;"</td>";
                  echo "<td bgcolor='#EAECEE'>".$row->A_Paterno;"</td>";
                  echo "<td bgcolor='#EAECEE'>".$row->A_Materno;"</td>";

                  "</tr>";
        }
      ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>`
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Empleados extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // Load the todo model to make it available 
    // to *all* of the controller's actions 
    $this->load->model('consultas_M');
  }


    public function busqueda(){
        if ($_POST) {
          $buscar = $this->input->post('buscar');

            } else {
                $buscar = '';
        }
        $data['empleados'] = $this->consultas_M->muestra($buscar);
    // 3. Render the view:
    $this->load->view('main/busqueda', $data);
    }   
}`
```

Model:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  } 

function muestra($bus)
{
  $this->db->like('interno', $bus);
  $this->db->or_like('Curp', $bus);
  $this->db->or_like('Nombre', $bus);
  $this->db->or_like('A_Paterno', $bus);
  $this->db->or_like('A_Materno', $bus);

   $q= $this->db ->get('empleados');
  if($q -> num_rows() >=0){
    return $q;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
  }
```

Comment: So basically you want to be able to edit the item? Just make a controller with method `edit($id)` and have a link to it via /somecontroller/edit/$id and in that method use the id to get the details from the database. There is no need to save or pass this information.

Comment: Well I actually need to save the results, the real database is way larger than that, let´s say more than 1000 employees, and the search query could show more than one result, let´s say user searches for "Alex" and I have 4 Alex in my database, I want to choose the right Alex based on the other columns like age, address, etc. so that´s why I want to "click" that person and get the info to pass it to other form.

Comment: Yea and you can't save 1000 results in a session or cookie, and the larger your db gets the more unlikely it is you can save the result in memory. Especially on concurrent page loads. There is simply no way around it. You'll have the query the db again for the individual record or pass the data from your table to inputs via jQuery (assuming your table has all the input values). Presumably you use unique ids? In which case the right Alex has id say 4 and then you can just use my previous comment...